# Django русификация админки

Tags: django, django-admin

Есть проект на Django 1.8, мне необходимо русифицировать часть админки которая, генерируется некоторыми модулями типа

django-celery-beat,
django-celery-results

Вся остальная часть нормально локализована, только эти разделы нет.

Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Форкнуть https://github.com/celery/django-celery-beat
2. Клонировать форк на свой компьютер
3. Создать ветку russification
4. Создать в репозитории каталог locale
5. Запустить `django-admin makemessages -l ru`
6. Открыть файл locale\ru\LC_MESSAGES\django.po удобным для вас текстовым редактором и вбить перевод
7. Запушить изменения
8. Создать pull request
9. Повторить шаги для django-celery-results

Comment: то есть никакого готового механизма нет для таких задач?  Правильно я понимаю, что можно клонировать репозиторий, потом сделать 5-й и 6-й пункт и эти файлы скопировать себе в проект в папку  locale\ru\LC_MESSAGES\django.po.

Comment: Механизм есть, перевода нет. И да, можно не делиться сделанным вами переводом, просто скопировать каталог locale в свой проект.

Comment: я потом поделюсь, просто мне же эту задачу решить нужно в ближайшее время, в пока мой пулл-реквест примут. времени пройдёт довольно много